# Xcode 6.4 displaying errors that aren't there?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just started programming in Swift, and Xcode (on numerous occasions) has displayed an error when there wasn't one. How do I know this if I just started? Because the error goes away when I, say, backspace one of the characters in the line and then re-add it. It's like some strange glitch that keeps reporting errors that don't exist, and the only way to get rid of them is to change something and undo the change (or, in some cases, add a newline between lines). Does this happen to other people?

Answer (score 2):

What I have found is helpful is to just ignore errors until you are ready to build and run. Sometimes errors just go away at compilation time, and the ones that remain are the "real" errors that are not allowing your program to run properly.

Comment: That's what I've started doing :/. I guess I'm just used to IntelliJ, which in my opinion trumps Xcode, but that could just be cause I'm used to it.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode > Preferences > General > Show live issues: *uncheck*.

Another alternative is to toggle off the display of the error tags (Control-Command-M). The error markers will still flash on and off in the margin, but at least the description of the "error" won't impose itself on your code.

Comment: Wouldn't I want to see if I have a legitimate error though? I realize that they will probably surface at compile time but one of the advantages of an IDE is that it shows it to you as you type. I don't mind the error checking, just the incorrect ones.

Comment: The problem you are complaining about is that you see the errors while you're typing. This solves that. You'll still see them when you try to Build / Run. So if you want to know "Have I got errors?", build and you'll find out.

Comment: My problem is different. Yes, I'm complaining about errors, but these errors are WRONG and I'm wondering why Xcode is showing them to me in the first place. It's frustrating and distracting to have correct code that displays incorrect errors. I was simply wondering if this was a bug that other people are experiencing.

Comment: They are not wrong. The letter "l" alone on a line is an error. The word "let" alone on a line is an error. Your code is basically _always_ an error until you finish typing "let x = 7" or whatever you are typing.

Comment: Actually now that I'm looking at it, Xcode appears to have "delayed" errors. So if I type something incorrectly and then change it to something correct, the old error will hold until I make a another change. Quite annoying if you ask me.

Comment: Of course it's annoying. It's more than annoying. It's idiotic. That's why I recommend unchecking "Show live issues". Just turn it off. Move on. Clearly you haven't even _tried_ doing any of what I suggested.

Comment: I did indeed try it and I determined that it was not what I wanted. For the reasons I stated above.

Comment: Okay, but then your question is basically just a moan, not a question.

Comment: In my case I had error that were displaying for files that no longer existed in the project. The project was building, but the errors were persisting in the Issue Navigator. To get rid of them, I had to disable "Show Live Errors", build my app, and then re-enable "Show Live Errors"